# How do I switch on emacs keys in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

If I go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys, change the scheme to "Emacs", and click apply, nothing happens.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.1 on Fedora 14. Is there something I'm missing or is this just broken? Is there a workaround that doesn't involve manually entering all of the shortcuts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't know about the built in Emacs keys, I do enjoy using Emacs+ for Eclipse: http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I have the same problem that switching the scheme doesn't make any changes to any of the key bindings.

Comment: OK, got it working. Not sure what the problem was before (just uninstalled the emacs+ OS X plugins and restored defaults before switching to emacs+).

Comment: The built in emacs scheme still doesn't work though. Must be some sort of bug. This is a good solution though.

Answer (score 2):

The keybindings mechanism in Eclipse occasionally gets confused.  Briefly, you have to convince Eclipse to reset the bindings to the default before re-enabling your desired binding scheme.  A description of the procedure (that works most of the time) can be found at: http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus/keybinding.
Some users have found that they need to restart Eclipse more frequently than is outlined in the procedure...